# WatchOS - Apple Watch displays complications but iPhone does not

Tags: xcode, swiftui, watchos

I have an iOS app with an embedded WatchOS component.

- On WatchOS 9, which is supported by Apple Watch SE and Apple Watch Series 8, I can select complications from both the watch and the iPhone.
- However, on my Apple Watch Series 3 running WatchOS 8.7.1, I can only view complications on the device itself; the iPhone app cannot detect them.

While the complications themselves function properly, the problem is that I am unable to choose them from my phone. Is this WatchOS < 9 limitation?

Additional info:

- XCode 14.3
- IOS 16.4
- Deployment target 7.0
- Complications assets configured for each size